# What happens when we give an input other than the classes that we trained our model for?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, training-data, predict, mismatch

I have modeled a Dog and Cat classifier using TensorFlow and Keras with the help of online tutorials. The model seems to work fine for both the cat and dog images. However, when I give a bird image as the input to the trained model, the output turns out to be a dog, which is not the desirable output. So, what should actually happen when we give an input that belongs to a class other than the classes that we train our model for? Isn't it supposed to give something like a 'not detected' error or something? If yes, how does that actually work? Please explain. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think we need to understand what really the network does. The network learns parameters and ouput probabilities that it is a dog or a cat. It does not say this is a cat when you give it a cat picture and same for dog.  Instead, it says, for example when the input image is a dog, it says, this picture is 90% dog and 10% cat, and then we write a function to take the highest probability. For the case of the bird, it probably said 51% dog, 49% cat because it  was never trained on this image but the function that decides the class said its a dog.

Comment: Right. So,what if we want the model to accept only the classes we want it to classify as the correct input and omit any other input? Is there a way to train the model that way?

Comment: You can add an additional class/category for uninteresting images containing no real target and train your model with additional image data containing anything except targets.

Comment: would say exactly the same as @bit01 said

Comment: Sure. Will try figuring that out. Thanks and any updated response anytime would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The model will always give output based on the classes you have trained it on. The model is not intelligent by itself, you are the person making it intelligent by telling the categories (classes) of the pictures. If you want it to tell you if the new picture is of a bird then first you need to train the model on pictures of birds.

> Isn't it supposed to give something like a 'not detected' error or something?

No. Because, you are still giving it a valid picture. No matter what it contains. It will still try to find out the information from this picture based on what it has learned from Dogs and Cats pictures. In this new picture of Bird, it has found more similarities to dogs pictures that is why it is classifying it as a Dog picture.

Comment: I get it. But, is it possible that we train the model that says 'not a proper input' or something like that when we give some other input? How do we do that?

Comment: Well that is not possible, because models are trained to give outputs. On prediction, they assign probabilities to each class which has a sum of 1. What you can do is create a third class with labels `Unknown or something`. This will have random images other than Dogs or Cats. And, based on this this class's images the model should be able to define the Bird picture into `Unknown` class. ALso, have a look at this [paper](https://openreview.net/forum?id=BJluxbWC-).

Comment: Sure.. will go through that. Thanks!